# Drawing multiple vector graphics in R on one page with grImport

Tags: r, vector-graphics, grimport

I'm trying to use the `grImport` package to draw several vector graphics on one page:

```
grid.newpage()
grid.picture(pic1)
grid.picture(pic2)
```

This just draws over the older graphic. I'm looking for something similar to `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` with plots, but `mfrow` doesn't seem to work with `grid.picture`.

I know you can set `x` `y` `width` and `height` values in `grid.picture`, but is there a simpler way similar to `par`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(grImport)
hourglass <- new("Picture",
                 paths= list(new("PictureFill",
                                 x=c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                                 y=c(0, 0, 1, 1))),
                 summary= new("PictureSummary",
                              numPaths=1,
                              xscale=c(0, 1),
                              yscale=c(0, 1)))

g1 <- pictureGrob(hourglass, use.gc=FALSE,  gp=gpar(fill="red"))
g2 <- pictureGrob(hourglass, use.gc=FALSE,  gp=gpar(fill="blue"))

require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(g1,g2, ncol=2)
```

[image]